# Find and Replace and Looping Though a Table

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a user friendly excel interface to replace values in a large data set using vba.

I have a small table with the Columns "Replace What" and "Replace With" and the large data set in a worksheet together.

My goal is to hit a button and have a macro use the Find function on the data to look up the number in the Replace What Column and then paste in the data from the corresponding row of the Replace With column.

Here's my code so far:

```
Sub ReplaceItems()
Dim replaceList As Range

Set replaceList = ListItems("Table4").ListColummns("Replace What").DataBodyRange

Dim item As Range

For Each Cell In replaceList.Cells
    Cell.Offset(0, 1).Select.Copy
    item = ActiveWorksheet.Find(Cell.Value)
    item.Select.Paste

Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the sheet name that contains the large data set?  What is the sheet name that contains the replace what/replace with values?  Do those values start A2/B2 and go down? Should it replace partial matches or only whole matches?

Comment: Also, you may want to look into the Range.Replace method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary to quickly map the Replace What key to the Replace With values. Then check if a key appears in the cell's value (you can use a combination of Index-match and InStr/RegEx, but I would probably just loop through the cells). Finally delete the key from the cell and copy in the value, you can do this in one line using Left() and Right() functions

Ex. Using a dictionary

```
Sub dictionary()
    Dim key As String, value As String, var As Variant
    Dim d As Object
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    key = "my key"
    value = "my value"

    d.Add key, value
    d.Add key & 1, value & 1

    For Each var In d.keys
        MsgBox var & " : " & d.item(var)
    Next var
End Sub
```

Ex. Replace key with value

```
Sub ReplaceItems()
    Dim s As String, k As String, v As String, index As Integer
    s = "this is my key, I think"
    k = "key"
    v = "value"
    index = InStr(s, k)
    MsgBox Left(s, index - 1) & v & Right(s, Len(s) - index - Len(k) + 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I happen to have this kind of routine so I'll share.
Like what Alter posted, I used *Dictionary*.

```
Sub test()
    Dim RepList As Range, RepItem As Range
    Dim rng As Range, ldbase As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With Sheet1 '~~> contains your table, change to suit
        Set RepList = .Range("Table4[Replace What]")
    End With

    With Sheet2 '~~> contains your large database, change to suit
        '~~> transfer your database in an array
        '~~> I this example, my target is the whole column B with data.
        Set rng = .Range("B2", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        ldbase = Application.Transpose(rng) 'dumps range values to array
    End With

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        '~~> first transfer your list in Dictionary
        For Each RepItem In RepList
            If Not .Exists(RepItem.Value) Then
                .Add RepItem.Value, RepItem.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End If
        Next
        '~~> here is the actual find and replace
        For i = LBound(ldbase) To UBound(ldbase)
            If .Exists(ldbase(i)) Then ldbase(i) = .Item(ldbase(i))
        Next
        rng = Application.Transpose(ldbase) '~~> dumps array values to range
    End With
End Sub
```

HTH.

Comment: both +1: very heplful anserws!